# How to pass extra text or summary field to promentehus alertmanager webhook for ms teams

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I have following alert-rules.yaml

```
groups: 
- name: alert.rules 
  rules: 
  - alert: HostOutOfMemory 
    expr: ((node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) * 100) < 25
    for: 5m 
    labels: 
      severity: warning 
    annotations: 
      summary: "Host out of memory (instance {{ $labels.instance }})" 
      description: "Node memory is filling up (< 25% left)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}" 

  - alert: HostOutOfDiskSpace 
    expr: (sum(node_filesystem_free_bytes) / sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes) * 100) < 30
    # expr: (node_filesystem_avail{mountpoint="/"}  * 100) / node_filesystem_size{mountpoint="/"} < 50 
    for: 1s 
    labels: 
      severity: warning 
    annotations: 
      summary: "Host out of disk space (instance {{ $labels.instance }})" 
      description: "Disk is almost full (< 30% left)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}" 

  - alert: HostHighCpuLoad 
    expr: ((sum by(instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}[5m])) / on(instance) group_left sum by (instance)((irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{}[5m])))) * 100) > 80
    # expr: (sum by (instance) (irate(node_cpu{job="node_exporter_metrics",mode="idle"}[5m]))) > 80 
    for: 5m 
    labels: 
      severity: warning 
    annotations: 
      summary: "Host high CPU load (instance {{ $labels.instance }})" 
      description: "CPU load is > 80%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```

I have following alertmanager.yaml:

```
route:
  receiver: 'teams'
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m

receivers:
- name: 'teams'
  webhook_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    url: '<my-msteams-webhook-url>'
```

My alertmanager does receives the alerts fired by prometheus:

[image]

But it does not fire them back to MS teams.

I checked alertmanagers log. It has following message:

```
ts=2023-06-01T21:57:43.396Z caller=dispatch.go:352 level=error component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=1 err="teams/webhook[0]: notify retry canceled due to unrecoverable error after 1 attempts: unexpected status code 400: <my-msteams-webhook-url>: Summary or Text is required."
```

Notice that it says "Summary or Text is required.". I tried adding summary:

```
receivers:
- name: 'teams'
  webhook_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    url: 'my-msteams-webhook-url'
    http_config:
      summary: {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}
```

But now alertsmanager logs says:

```
Loading configuration file failed. field summary not found in type config.plain
```

I tried adding `params`:

```
    http_config:
      params:
          summary: {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}
```

But, now it gives me error

```
field params not found in type config.plain
```

How can I pass summary and/or text to MS Teams

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue???

Comment: If I recall it correct, I ended up using [prom2teams](https://github.com/idealista/prom2teams). Also, I guess, we can also do configurations in prom2teams, though I never tried. (There is also [prometheus-msteams](https://github.com/prometheus-msteams/prometheus-msteams)).

Comment: Yeah @Msa - I have done through prometheus-msteams, but one thing is can we customize the alert message that has been sent to teams?

I can see multiple unnecesary fields in the alert message in teams like 
               "app_kubernetes_io_component" , "app_kubernetes_io_managed_by ", "app_kubernetes_io_part_of "              

these fields should be filtered out when I recieve the alert in teams, do you have any idea like that?

Comment: Have you checked [alert-rules.yaml templating](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/#templating) and [prom2teams templating](https://github.com/idealista/prom2teams#templating)?